# jquery slider | amount depens on value of two sliders

Tags: jquery, uislider

I am stuck with following:

I have a product with different prices depending on size and order size.
Example.
    1x Small = $10,--
    2x Small = $17,50
    3x Small = $20,--

I have this in a slider, where handle sets order size and amount shows the price for the order.
But now I want to add another slider to select other productsize(medium, large)

The value of second slider will effect the total price.

```
If slider1 = 1 (piece)
and if slider2 = Small
then Price =  $ 10,--

If slider1 = 1 (pieces)
and if slider2 = Medium
then Price = $ 12,50
```

etc. etc.

So the total orderprice depends on value of both sliders. Can please someone help me out whith this?

Now I have this:

```
$(function() {
    var sizes1 = ["10", "17,50", "20"];
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: sizes1.length - 1,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(sizes1[ui.value]);
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val('10');
});​
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your both sliders?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vBVkL/ ?

Answer (score 0):

When slider is moved, change the total value:

```
var sizes1 = ["10", "17,50", "20"];
var sizes2 = ["12,50", "...", "..."];
var sizes3 = ["...", "...", "..."];

function calculateprice() {
    var slider1 = $("#slider1").slider("value");
    var slider2 = $("#slider2").slider("value");

    if (slider2 == 1) $("#amount").val(sizes1[slider1]); //Small
    if (slider2 == 2) $("#amount").val(sizes2[slider1]); //Medium
    //etc
}

//create your 2 slides
$("#slider1").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: sizes1.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        calculateprice();
    }
});

//etc
```